# ¿Como mejorar mi código en POO en python , para realizar el envió de un paquete y que no me permita hacer el mismo envió nuevamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, condiciones, objeto

Para esta parte deberás definir la clase PaqueteMejorado, la cual hereda de Paquete y tiene los siguientes cambios:

Un PaqueteMejorado no se deberá enviar si su emisor y su receptor son la misma persona.( Esto ya lo solucione creo )
Además, una misma instancia de PaqueteMejorado solo se podrá enviar una vez; si se intenta enviar una segunda vez, entonces NO se deberá realizar el segundo envio.

NOTA: No es necesario que redefinas la clase Paquete, puedes suponer que ya está definida (de manera equivalente a como Envió ya estaba definida para ambas preguntas anteriores)

```
class Envio:
def __init__(self, emisor:str, receptor:str):
    self.emisor = emisor
    self.receptor = receptor

def enviar(self):
    
    return 'Este paquete de ' + self.emisor + ' debe ser enviado a ' + self.receptor
  

class Paquete(Envio):
def __init__(self, emisor:str, receptor:str, max_volumen:float):
    super().__init__(emisor, receptor)
    self.max_volumen = max_volumen
    self.paquete_abierto= True
    

def agregar_producto(self, peso:float, volumen:float):
    
    self.peso=peso
    self.volumen= volumen
    self.paquete_abierto= False 
    if self.paquete_abierto is  True :
        return 'Poder agregar producto/s'
    else:
         return 'Abrir el paquete para poder agregar producto/s '

def cerrar(self):
    if self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:
        return 'El volumen es adecuado , podes cerrar  el paquete y llevarlo a zona de pesaje '
    else:
        return 'El volumen del producto no permite cerrar el paquete . '
    

def enviar(self):
    if self.peso <= 30 and self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:
        return 'El producto tiene peso adecuado menor de 30 y volumen adecuado  . Podes enviar  el paquete'
    elif self.peso > 30 and self.volumen <= self.max_volumen:
        return 'El volumen es adecuado , pero no el peso. No podes enviar el paquete'
    
    else:
        
        return 'Este producto excede el peso maximo de 30 y el volumen maximo . No podes enviar el paquete. Corregir volumen y peso '
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):

def check_persona(self):
    super().__init__(emisor,receptor,max_vol)
    
    if emisor == receptor:
        return 'El emisor y receptor son la misma persona . Revisar datos . No enviar  '
    
    
    if emisor != receptor :
        
        return 'Los datos de emisor y receptor estan chequeados y son correctos. Podes enviar.'

    
    


enviando_mi_paquete=Envio('Juan','Jose')
print(enviando_mi_paquete.enviar())
emisor='Juan'
receptor='Jose'
max_vol= 100

enviando_mi_paquete=Paquete(emisor,receptor,max_vol)
print(enviando_mi_paquete.agregar_producto(30 ,100))
print(enviando_mi_paquete.cerrar())
print(enviando_mi_paquete.enviar())
emisor='Marcelo'
receptor='Jose'
max_vol=100
enviando_mi_paquete=PaqueteMejorado(emisor, receptor,max_vol)
print(enviando_mi_paquete.check_persona())
```

Comment: Deberías tratar de aprender a resolver los problemas en vez de pedir que otros te resuelvan la tarea de la facu.

Comment: @Cesarandió, si no estás dispuesto a ayudar a los que tienen problemas que resolver dentro de su código, tal vez este no sea el sitio adecuado para ti, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Por supuesto que ingreso a la plataforma a ayudar, pero si copian y pegan el ejercicio sin investigar, sin intentar hacer nada, me parece que sólo le estás haciendo la tarea a otros, eso se llama "trabajo" no "ayuda". Para mí esta comunidad está para ayudar a aprender, pero con cero esfuerzo del estudiante no hay profesor que sirva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):
    def __init__(self, emisor,receptor,max_volumen):
        super().__init__(emisor,receptor,max_volumen) 
        self.enviado = False 
        
    def enviar(self): 
        if not self.enviado:
            if self.emisor != self.receptor:                  
                super().enviar()                    
                self.enviado = True
            else:
                self.enviado = False
```

Comment: Gracias Ivan. Por la aclaracion me ayudo mucho tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a, como dice el ejercicio, asumir que la clase paquete ya está definida y no la tenemos que alterar. Ningún problema. Aquí, es donde entra en juego la magia de la jerarquía de clases.

##### Glosario para entender la respuesta

- instancia: aquel objeto especial que se crea cuando ponemos parentesis al lado de una clase. Ej: `instancia = clase()`
- constructor: aquel método que inicializa los datos de la instancia. En Python, un constructor se crea implementando el método `__init__`

##### Jerarquía de clases

Primero, hay que saber que una instancia es el objeto especial que se obtiene cuando ponés parentesis al lado de una clase.
Cuando Python busca un método o atributo en una clase lo hace en este orden:

```
instancia -> clase de la instancia -> clase padre -> clase abuelo ...
```

Lo que hace es, por prueba y error ver si el atributo existe. Y cuando lo encuentra, detiene la busqueda.

Ante la clase PaqueteMejorado sería así:

```
instancia de PaqueteMejorado -> PaqueteMejorado -> Paquete ...
```

##### ¿Por que todo esto?

Por que aquí está el truco. Si no declaramos el método enviar en la clase PaqueteMejorado, se ejecutará el enviar de la clase Paquete. Para evitar esto, podemos poner algo en medio del camino, un método enviar en la clase PaqueteMejorado

```
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):
     def enviar(self, emisor, receptor, max_vol):
         [validación del paquete aquí]
```

Pero nosotros queríamos la funcionalidad original también, ¿cómo hacemos? Ya vamos a eso.

##### ¿Que hace super().metodo?

super() es una función que, ejecutada en un método de clase, nos devuelve un objeto especial que nos ayuda a llamar métodos de una clase padre sobre una clase hija.

Hacer `super().hola(...)` es equivalente a `padre.hola(instancia, ...)`

Hay que hacerlo así, ya que si no, se generaría una recursión infinita, ya que al buscar el método, terminaríamos encontrandonos con el método que se ejecuta actualmente, lo ejecutaríamos y repetiríamos la busqueda, ejecutando nuevamente la función (ver jerarquia de clases).

Dicho esto, el `super().__init__` está de más, lo unico que hace es llamar al constructor, lo cual no nos da nada a favor en este caso. La forma común de usar esto es para ejecutar el constructor de una clase padre en el constructor de una clase hija.

En su lugar, podemos primero hacer la validación y luego, si todo dió ok, llamamos a la "versión original" de enviar:

```
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):
     def enviar(self, emisor, receptor, max_vol):
         [validación del paquete aquí]

         super().enviar()
```

##### Un solo envío

Habitualmente, cuando esto sucede, se utiliza un atributo que tenga un booleano e indique si la acción se efectuó o no.
Este atributo, al cual llamaremos enviado, lo inicializamos en False, pues aun no enviamos el paquete mejorado.
Luego, envolvemos todo el cuerpo del método en un condicional que solo se ejecutará si enviado es False. Dentro de la función, cambiamos enviado a True y listo! En las siguientes llamadas a enviado, como enviado es True, el condicional dará False y el método no hará nada más.

##### Finalmente...

El código nos queda así:

```
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):
     def __init__(self, ...):
         super().__init__(...)
         self.enviado = False

     def enviar(self, emisor, receptor, max_vol):
         if not self.enviado:
             [validación del paquete aquí]

             super().enviar()
             self.enviado = True
```

Comment: Perdón por la respuesta larga, pero también quería ayudar a que entendieras como funciona Python. Lo bueno de este lenguaje es que es bastante facil de leer. Imagina java, todo se hace a través de POO y el equivalente al not es "!"

Comment: Tu respuesta responde mi pregunta y mas .

Comment: Me alegro de que te ayude c:

Comment: @Ivan si esta respuesta ha sido la que te ha ayudado a resolver el problema, te invito a marcarla como aceptada, pues eso informará a futuros visitantes. Encontrarás más información en [qué hacer si me responden](/help/someone-answers). Si no recuerdas bien como funcionamos por aquí, puedes hacer de nuevo el [tour].